# Grid Layout Width Issue

Tags: android, user-interface, grid-layout

I have been developing an app for which I also need to handle the UI stuff too.

Heres my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2" >
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
    .
    .
  </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now the problem is the width of the right column. It is exceeding the devices' width. For example the name of the mobile which has an attribute of `android:layout_gravity` set as Center. But its not working as expected as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: Device Screenshot]

What should I be using to keep the width with in limits as the text is dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem using a GridLayout with `fill_horizontal`. The solution for me was to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` so you might want to try that for all views in your second column.

[Source](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.co.at/2012/01/gridlayout-view-clipping-issues.html)